# Refractive index dispersion relation of stainless steel

Tags: optics, resource-recommendations, material-science, refraction, dispersion

I am lookin for the refractive index dispersion relation of stainless steel.
I tried to search for it at https://refractiveindex.info/ and on google but I couldn't find anything.

I mainly need the refractive index for the range of $300\space nm$ to  $650\space nm$.

If anyone knows a book/paper that has this information it will be much helpfull.

Comment: Lacking a documentation of an experimental value, I would take a weighted average of the indices of the components.  x% the index of iron,  y% the index of carbon, z% the index of ...  etc.   Of course, how much faith you place in the result depends on what you will use the result for.